# How to find the repetitive/duplicate array values and display them in output ?

Tags: java, arrays

I have tried the below program and i am stuck please assist me.Below is my program

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrintNosandRepetition

{

public static void main(String[] args) 

{

int a[] = new int[] {1,3,4,5,6,3,2,4,6,7,9,4,12,3,4,6,8,9,7,6,43,2,4,7,7,5,2,1,3,4,6,311,1};

    for (int i=0; i< a.length; i++){

    System.out.print(a[i]+ " ");

    }
    for (i=1, j<a.length; j++)


    }
```

The output has to be is the fashion "1- repeated 3 times".etc

Comment: This becomes easier if you normalize your data set, e.g. sort it first

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the original array and then loop through it to scan the elements one by one. This will run in `O(nlogn)`.

Or you can use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` which will store for each number it's number of occurences. This solutions runs in `O(n)` but uses extra memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a[] = new int[] {1,3,4,5,6,3,2,4,6,7,9,4,12,3,4,6,8,9,7,6,43,2,4,7,7,5,2,1,3,4,6,311,1};

HashMap occurrenceMap = new HashMap()<Integer, Integer>;
int number;
Integer occurrences; //accepts null

for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    number = a[i];
    occurrences = occurrenceMap.get(number);
    if (occurrences == null) { //had no occurrences until this point
        occurrenceMap.put(number, 1);
    }
    else {
        occurrenceMap.put(number, occurrences+1);
    }
}

//iterate over your map and print the pairs
```

Can't test it right now so I apologize for any eventual syntax errors.

Comment: Whats this HashMap? what does it do ? Also why are we using this "<Integer, Integer>"  ?

Comment: It maps some object (Key) to another object (Value). Creating a new HashMap()<Integer, Integer> means that it will map Integers (which are the elements of your array) to other Integers (their respective number of occurrences). You can find a very good description with examples here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm